# Is there an alternate to metamorph script tags in Ember.js?

Tags: ember.js

I am evaluating Ember.js for my next project. I am loving the binding mechanism so far, but have a question about the approach. As per the docs "In order to know which part of your HTML to update when an underlying property changes, Handlebars will insert marker elements with a unique ID." I can probably live with these tags but they are very distracting (see example below). Is the rationale behind this approach discussed anywhere. Were any alternatives considered?

```
<tbody>
    <script id="metamorph-0-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
    <script id="metamorph-1-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
    <tr>
        <td class="quote-name">
            <script id="metamorph-7-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
            Apple
            <script id="metamorph-7-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
        </td>
        <td class="quote-code">...</td>
        <td class="quote-value">...</td>
        <td class="quote-bid">...</td>
        <td class="quote-offer">...</td>
    </tr>
    ...
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The rationale that Metamorph uses script tags, as I know it, is that script tags can appear within the DOM anywhere without breaking anything visually. This fact becomes very important when you think about it because it allows for a way to make just about anything in the DOM watchable by the framework. Thus enabling all of the binding "magic" that makes Ember so great.

Earlier last year I do remember some of the discussions on the IRC channel about this and yes alternatives were considered but script tags won.

Comment: Except that it does affect and break things visually. No CSS pseudo classes like :first-child :nth-child(odd) work because if this. Thats a mayor thing, whole features in the CSS spec are unusable.

Comment: @pangratz that's not supported in every browser, and a lot of existing code around needs to be fixed for other reasons. For instance, jQuery.timeago breaks because of the Metamorph script tags.